# django.middleware.csrf.get_token() usage

Tags: django, django-csrf, csrf-protection

Consider the following scenario: the page is loaded with `{% csrf_token %}` in the `<form>`. Later the submissions of this form (including the hidden csrf_token) are performed using ajax (post) without reloading the page.
On the server side as I understand the token should be sent back to client and replace the one which is in the `<form>`, because the token can be renewed depending on its' lifespan (by the way, when the token is regenerated?)
To get the token and send with response I'm thinking on using the django.middleware.csrf.get_token(), but in the code it seems that it will just return the one which was sent from client.
So will the get_token() return the up to date one?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve your csrf token in your js using

```
var csrf_token = $(this).data('csrf');  // $(this) refers to your form in your html
```

Then:

```
$('#yoursubmitbutton').click(function() {
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token, other_data: other_data },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data['success']=='true') {
                    // Handles success
                } else {
                    // Handles failure failed.
                }

                // Any logic you want
            },
            error: function() {
                                   // Error handling
            }
        }) 
});  // click event
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! but I guess you misunderstood my question which is: does django.middleware.csrf.get_token() return already re-generated token (if it is re-generated) or not.